# Nginx variable for subdomain?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I need a Guru's advice.

On Nginx's `conf` file, I would like to get the subdomain as a variable in order to redirect accesses as follow.

- ACCESS: `http://userX.example.com/?hoo=bar`
- REDIRECT: `http://example.com/userX/?hoo=bar`

But I get

- REDIRECT: `http://example.com/userX.example.com/?hoo=bar`

My current `_http.conf` settings are like below. So obviously it works so.

```
## default HTTP
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  default_server;
    return       301 http://example.com/$host$request_uri;
}
```

Are there any vaiables or ways to do like below?

```
## default HTTP
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  default_server;
    return       301 http://example.com/$subdomain$request_uri;
}
```

I know if the subdomain part is limited it can be redirected, but I have to add them each time and I want it to keep as simple as possible.

Is there any simple way to do so?

**[ENV]**: CentOS:7.3.1611, nginx: nginx/1.13.3, *.example.com is targetted to the same server in NS settings.

---

#### Conclusion (2017/12/13)

Use a regular expression:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.example\.com$;
    return       301 http://example.com/$subdomain$request_uri;
}
```

Ref: [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318758/nginx-variable-for-subdomain/45321927#45321927), [Document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use a regular expression in the `server_name` to extract the part you need as a named capture. For example:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  ~^(?<name>.+)\.example\.com$;
    return       301 http://example.com/$name$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.

Comment: Wow, thank you! That worked perfectly both http and ssl!

Comment: Also thank you for the document link! I thought I checked there but I wasn't. (>_<)

Comment: I also have this problem, but instead of using a `redirect`, I want to use `proxy_pass`.