# nginx ssl_certificate regex

Tags: django, ssl, nginx

when i use this code, i'm get error "No such file or directory" , but in docs writed what i can use variables

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.domain$;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$sub.domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$sub.domain/privkey.pem;

    location /.well-known {
        alias /var/www/.well-known;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://$sub.domain:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some topics that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318758/nginx-variable-for-subdomain and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563071/how-to-get-subdomain-of-url-in-nginx

Comment: You should be able to use `$ssl_server_name`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith, i'm use like this `ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem;`, but still get `nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)`

Comment: What version of Nginx are you using?

Comment: @RichardSmith 1.14.0. i thought i use last version

Comment: You need version 1.15.9 to use variables in `ssl_certificate` directives. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) for details.